# WP REST API v2 give a mixed up output for custom taxonomies on custom posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wpml

I used a theme (with included plugins) that created custom taxonomies and post_types on WP.
Both are exposed on REST endpoints with `show_in_rest => true`.
All were doing great until I realized the output of custom taxonomies are mixed up.

**Example**

post_type = pokemon
taxonomy = pokemon_category

request:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/pokemon
```

output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "ditto",
    "pokemon_category": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "snorlax",
    "pokemon_category": [
      1,
      1
    ]
  }
]
```

expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "ditto",
    "pokemon_category": [1]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "snorlax",
    "pokemon_category": [1]
  }
]
```

I saw nothing odds on the source code and it seems already followed a [handbook from wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Update:

It seems it's the problem of WPML. The problem is shown when I set the post type as translatable with: "Translatable: only show translated items". The issue disappears when I choose "Translatable: use translation if available or fallback to default language"

Answer (score 0):

what is the expected result?
mixed up = the “pokemon_category” array?

Comment: I realize you can't leave comments, but this isn't an answer.